# GridView problem with resizing

Tags: android, gridview

I have a gridview with a button adapter based on this [tutorial](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/09/android-creating-a-custom-adapter-for-gridview-buttonadapter/).
**The problem:** When sliding up or down, right or left on the gridview, button resize for some reason. e.g from 85*85 px it get's to 100+ on 100+ and when moving finger back it get's to default. I don't really know why this is happening, ive searched alot and didnt find anything. Am I only one who has this bug? I tested it on a real phone too - same.

Comment: I have a similar problem, though my linear layouts (with 1 imageview and 1 textview inside) get about half the size when moving the gridview around. It always happens with only a few of the (in my case 8) items inside the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

I would change attributes of GridView and only restrict Button height and see how it behaves

```
<GridView 
  android:id="@+id/gridview"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:numColumns="3"
  android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
  android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
  android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
/>
```